# How can i use a Global Variable to hide/show a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

on a web page for mobile devices only i have a magnifying glass search icon. when clicking the icon the div appears which contains the search box. if the user decides not to search for something, and clicks anywhere except the search box div, it should close the div.

in my code below the global variable isn’t working. i tried to set it TRUE in  the first function 
but in the second function it’s not TRUE. i know this has to do with variable scope and i have tried numerous variations on this but so far nothing i’ve tried is working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var searchDivOn = '';
jQuery('a#mobile-search').click(function(event){
    jQuery('#block-search-form').fadeIn('slow');
    searchDivOn = true;
    alert(searchDivOn);
    event.stopPropagation();

  });

 jQuery(':not(#block-search-form)').click(function(){  
      if(searchDivOn == true){
      jQuery('#block-search-form').fadeOut('fast');
      console.log('hello');
      searchDivOn = false;
      }
    });
})//End jQ doc ready
```

note: if i don’t use a global variable the second function fires regardless and closes the div immediately after opening.

Comment: Create the variable outside the `$(docment).ready()`

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the target of the event and see if it's a descendant of `#mobile-search` or `#mobile-search` itself. You can do this using `.closest()`.

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if ($target.closest('#mobile-search').length === 0) {
    /* Then did not click inside #mobile-search */
  }
});
```

Here's a small demo: http://jsbin.com/tolitimuma/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm on the mobile, so brevity.   You could add an event listener to the window/document, and if the target isn't in your search elements, hide it.

Clicking your magnifying glass should probably put focus on the search input box so thee usability flows more  (they have to conscientiously click away to make it close) .

Comment: The problem with delegating is that any click handler with `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event bubbling to the required level. It's far more reliable to attach a click handler to a (transparent) mask that is shown/hidden in sympathy with the search form - ie make the search form modal;

Comment: That's a wonderful suggestion, to layer a mask between search and content.  You should rewrite it as an answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: In short - it'd be like:   On revealing your search box -- in between your search box and the HTML page (z-index) you draw a full-page/full-size invisible mask (a DIV that takes up the whole viewport) - and then your search box on  top of that.    Then -- add an onclick event to the mask DIV which hides the mask div and your search box.   That way you're not messing with bubble events of clicking away into the document.   Essentially, exactly how jQueryUI does their modal dialogs.    You could just use jQuery UI dialogs and place it where you want.  Let *it* handle the click away via options.

Answer (score 1):

Pur your var declaration outside of the jquery document ready

Comment: i tried, it goes and ahead and executes the second block because it's ON, or True.